# Problem in installation of gedit in Ubuntu18.04 LTS on Windows 10

Tags: sudo, gedit

I downloaded Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store and I have installed it.
I tried downloading `gedit` using

```
$ sudo apt install gedit
```

I got this problem:

[image]

How do I resolve this problem?

**EDIT:** Attempts to resolve the problem

Attempt 1: I used `sudo` after suggestion and it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: @Prvt_Yadv I tried sudo but it didn't work.Check the edit I did once

Comment: Windows subsystem for Linux (WSL) does not support any GUI app such as `gedit`. It is text only interface. Try using `vim` or `nano`

Comment: Installing an app in Ubuntu needs 2 commands. First, `sudo apt update`. Second, `sudo apt install nano`. You can use `apt-get` instead of `apt`. The `apt-get` is old syntax.

Comment: Please do not post images of terminal windows. It's hard to read and someone who wants to help cannot copy-paste the commands you've run. Instead, [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1171705/edit) your post to add the text from your terminal using the appropriate [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).